# AJAX data contains one or more words..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

I'm using an AJAX post to submit form data and this is working well.

I'm not trying to show an message based on success or failure..

I've got this so far:

```
        alert("Yehh.. Saving Data.");
        $.ajax({
        url:'go.php?doit=1',
        data:$("form").serialize(),
        type:'POST' })
        .done(function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
        })
```

When the submit completes `data` will contain either nothing or the text back from the update saying why it failed.

As an example I'd like to show an alert if there are no errors returned.

Any idea how I can do that?

If there are errors, I'd like to show an different alert.

Comment: you are looking for `success` and `error` callbacks: read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Not if the server returns an empty string and status code 200. This would be the case for the HTTP request working, but the validation (or whatever else) throwing an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would  return a response from the server in both cases, just to be safer...
but it will work if you don't, unless the server had a problem, no string was returned and you assumed you had a success! Do you see the problem here?

On the server:

Success:

```
$response = {
    'status': 1,
    'message': 'Success'
}
```

Error:

```
$response = {
    'status': 0,
    'message': 'Some error'
}
```

The Ajax function:

```
$.post( "go.php?doit=1",
    {
       data : $("form").serialize()
    },
    function(data) {
         if(data.status == 1){
         // success! Do something
     }
     else{
         // error! Do something! eg: alert message
         alert(data.message)
     }
 });
```

Comment: Heh, beat me to it. @Rocket - while my answer technically solves the problem as you've posted it, this is the better way to go.

Comment: You actually wrote that: "It might be a better idea to return a JSON object ". Also, that "$.ajax" function is just a waste of time :D

Comment: This is SO, not Code Review ;)

Comment: sorry If I offended you. It was not my intention. I'm just saying that you were right in pointing out that he should return a json object. But I keep the part that the "$ajax" function is a waste of time when you have "$post" ;-)

Comment: I'm not offended haha. I totally agree with you. Just trying to modify OP's code as little as possible so as not to throw him off :)

Comment: Thanks - I've implemented this and it does do what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that your HTTP request is sending, and that you are evaluating deliberate return values (for example you are validating your form, and returning an empty string to signify an error), you can do the following:

**JS**:

```
  alert("Yehh.. Saving Data.");
  $.ajax({
      url: 'go.php?doit=1',
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      type: 'POST'
  })
  .done(function (data) {
      if ( typeof data !== 'string' )
          console.log("data is not a string. Consider 'return false' if this is unexpected?")
      if ( data.length > 0 )
          console.log("There was data returned")
      if ( data.length === 0 )
          console.log("Empty string returned!")
  })
```

It might be a better idea to return a JSON object with the exact data you are trying to pass (such as a `valid` or `fail` flag, along with a message)